# Replace Text node with React Element via react-native-render-html in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dom, react-native-render-html

### Problem

I am using [react-native-render-html](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html) to render some html in *React Native*. The problem is that this html contains some placeholders like `{{{placeholder:items:0}}}` which should be replaced with a *React Element*.

### Code

I am using the `onText` function currently as outlined in this [example](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html):

```
  function onText(text) {
    const toReplace = text.data.match(gemstoneRegex);

    if (toReplace?.length) {
      let [placeholder] = toReplace;
      placeholder = placeholder.replace(/\{/g, "");
      placeholder = placeholder.replace(/\}/g, "");

      const [name, position] = placeholder.split(":items:");

      text.data =
        (
          <Gemstone
            stones={[gemstones[name]?.de[position]]}
            displayTitle={gemstones[name]?.de[0]?.displaytitle || name}
            fieldName={name}
          />
        ) || `${name} couldn't be replaced!`;
    }
  }
```

This would work fine for a simple text string, but unfortunately not for a *React Element*. Is there a way to do this? The `onElement` function seems to have utility methods to add and remove elements. Is that also possible for text nodes?

Comment: That will not work. `onText` works for DOM nodes, not React elements. What you can do:

(1) In `onElement`, look for text children. When you find a text matching this regex, replace the text child with a custom element such as `<gemstone></gemstone>`
(2) [Register `gemstone` HTLM element.](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/guides/custom-renderers#example-registering-a-new-tag)
(3) [Define a custom renderer for `gemstone`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/guides/custom-renderers#minimal-example).